# SQL - Nested Statement that would return if all values are true.

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically I have a table of job orders and a table of individual tasks on each job.

Table: Job_Order
jobId
customerId
etc.

Table: Job_Task
taskId
jobId
isComplete

What I would like is a nested statement to populate a data grid to say if every task on the Job Order is complete or not.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: SQL Server CE actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: You should always try and show people you've researched and attempted this.  Honestly - this was pretty easy and it should be something you could have solved yourself in a short amount of time.

Here's the code as I understand it from your brief requirement:

```
DECLARE @Job_Order TABLE 

(
  ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  CustomerID INT
)

DECLARE @Job_Task TABLE (
  ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  Job_ID INT,
  Complete INT DEFAULT (0)
)

INSERT INTO @Job_Order (CustomerID) VALUES (1),(2),(1),(1),(2),(3),(3)
INSERT INTO @Job_Task (Job_ID, Complete) VALUES (1,1),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(5,1)

SELECT 
  [order].ID [Order ID],
  [order].CustomerID [Customer],
  CASE WHEN ISNULL(Complete,0) = 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END [Job Complete]
 FROM @job_Order [order]
LEFT JOIN @Job_Task [task] ON [order].ID = [task].Job_ID
```

If you need anything explained, let me know.